# How do I get All ID, Name values and location into array from my Json Object

Tags: javascript, json

SO i have json object caleld tabledata array, lets say i want to iterate all objects inside it and grab ids, so output returns 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 and I can also do name, location etc. So  i want to select one key and i need all the available values inside.

I have tried looping the object but didint work for me.

```
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    JSONObject object = (JSONObject) array.get(i);

    String id = object.get("id");
    //and so on
}

var tabledata = [
    {id:1, name:"Oli Bob", location:"United Kingdom", gender:"male", rating:1, col:"red", dob:"14/04/1984"},
    {id:2, name:"Mary May", location:"Germany", gender:"female", rating:2, col:"blue", dob:"14/05/1982"},
    {id:3, name:"Christine Lobowski", location:"France", gender:"female", rating:0, col:"green", dob:"22/05/1982"},
    {id:4, name:"Brendon Philips", location:"USA", gender:"male", rating:1, col:"orange", dob:"01/08/1980"},
    {id:5, name:"Margret Marmajuke", location:"Canada", gender:"female", rating:5, col:"yellow", dob:"31/01/1999"},
    {id:6, name:"Frank Harbours", location:"Russia", gender:"male", rating:4, col:"red", dob:"12/05/1966"},
    {id:7, name:"Jamie Newhart", location:"India", gender:"male", rating:3, col:"green", dob:"14/05/1985"},
    {id:8, name:"Gemma Jane", location:"China", gender:"female", rating:0, col:"red", dob:"22/05/1982"},
    {id:9, name:"Emily Sykes", location:"South Korea", gender:"female", rating:1, col:"maroon", dob:"11/11/1970"},
    {id:10, name:"James Newman", location:"Japan", gender:"male", rating:5, col:"red", dob:"22/03/1998"},
];
```

Comment: looks like the code you're writing is NOT javascript - is it perhaps JAVA? The two are not related, so, please confirm what language you are using

Answer (score 1):

In javascript, like this.

```js
var tabledata = [
    {id:1, name:"Oli Bob", location:"United Kingdom", gender:"male", rating:1, col:"red", dob:"14/04/1984"},
    {id:2, name:"Mary May", location:"Germany", gender:"female", rating:2, col:"blue", dob:"14/05/1982"},
    {id:3, name:"Christine Lobowski", location:"France", gender:"female", rating:0, col:"green", dob:"22/05/1982"},
    {id:4, name:"Brendon Philips", location:"USA", gender:"male", rating:1, col:"orange", dob:"01/08/1980"},
    {id:5, name:"Margret Marmajuke", location:"Canada", gender:"female", rating:5, col:"yellow", dob:"31/01/1999"},
    {id:6, name:"Frank Harbours", location:"Russia", gender:"male", rating:4, col:"red", dob:"12/05/1966"},
    {id:7, name:"Jamie Newhart", location:"India", gender:"male", rating:3, col:"green", dob:"14/05/1985"},
    {id:8, name:"Gemma Jane", location:"China", gender:"female", rating:0, col:"red", dob:"22/05/1982"},
    {id:9, name:"Emily Sykes", location:"South Korea", gender:"female", rating:1, col:"maroon", dob:"11/11/1970"},
    {id:10, name:"James Newman", location:"Japan", gender:"male", rating:5, col:"red", dob:"22/03/1998"}
];

for(let i = 0; i < tabledata.length; i++) {
    const object = tabledata[i];
    console.log(object.id)
}

// or
tabledata.map(object => {console.log(object.id)})
```